# Text in textfield jumps when blured

Tags: appcelerator

I am using latest SDK.

I am trying to create a form in Appcelerator (iOS) but when I focus on a field and enter the text and then focus on another textfield then the text in the field I just edited jumps up 1 pixel. How can I get this to stop moving?

```
var textfield = Titanium.UI.createTextField ({ 

        color:'#333', 
        font: {fontFamily: 'Ganero'},
        hintText: args.placeholder, 
        passwordMask: args.password,
        appearance:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_APPEARANCE_ALERT,
        autocapitalization:Titanium.UI.TEXT_AUTOCAPITALIZATION_NONE,
        width:180, 
        top: 20,
        left: 100, 
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        keyboardToolbarColor: '#000'

    });
```

Comment: Could you provide more code (second text field -- any containing views, etc)?

Comment: Any luck with this? I have the exact same problem.